# Unclear on distributional derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, dual-spaces

Suppose we have a distribution $\phi \in D'(\mathbb{R}^n)$. The distributional derivative of $\phi$ is defined as
$$\phi'(g) = -\phi(g'), \quad \forall g \in C^\infty_C(\mathbb{R}^n).$$
I am clear on this definition and how it is motivated. What has been confusing me is perhaps to due with terminology.

Suppose we look at the example of the Heaviside function:
$$H(x) \begin{cases} 1, \quad x>0\\ 0, \quad x\leq 0.\end{cases}$$
We can define a distribution $\phi_H$ as
$$\phi_H(g) =\langle H, g\rangle = \int H g dx.$$
In textbooks you see that the derivative of the Heaviside function is calculated as
$$\langle H', g \rangle = \int H' g dx = -\int Hg'dx = -\int_0^\infty g' dx = g'(0) = \langle\delta, g'\rangle$$
and so we conclude that $H' = \delta$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac-delta function.

My question is do we say that the function $H$ has derivative $\delta$, or that the distribution induced by $H$ (what I had called $\phi_H$) has derivative $\delta$? I assume it is the latter, but I see a lot of sources say statements such as "the derivative of the Heaviside function is the Dirac-delta function". Is this merely abuse of notation, or do they mean to say "the distribution induced by the Heaviside function is equal to the Dirac-delta function/distribution".

Further, is there some other connection where one implies the other? From my reading it seems that if a function $f$ induces a distribution $\phi_f$, and $f$ is differentiable, then the distributional derivative $\phi'_f$ is equal to the distribution induced by $f'$, $\phi_{f'}$. Can we say anything more?

Comment: The motivation for this definition is given by integration by parts. Assume that $f$ and $g$ are smooth and compactly supported (lighter assumptions work as well), then $\int_\limits{-\infty}^\infty f'g\,dx=-\int_\limits{-\infty}^\infty fg'\,dx$.

Comment: @yona sure, but OP says in the beginning *I am clear on this definition and how it is motivated.*

Comment: @user580918 woops that was a misreading. I read it as "I am unclear..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\phi_H$ be the distribution induced by $H$. Then the statement is that $(\phi_H)’=\delta$. Also, the proof you gave is wrong. It should be stated as follows: for any $g\in \mathcal{D}(\Bbb{R})$,
\begin{align}
\langle (\phi_H)’, g\rangle &:=-\langle \phi_H,g’\rangle\\
&:=-\int_{\Bbb{R}}H(x)g’(x)\,dx\\
&=-\int_{0}^{\infty}g’(x)\,dx\\
&=g(0)\\
&=\langle \delta,g\rangle.
\end{align}
Hence, $(\phi_H)’=\delta$. And yes, it is the usual abuse of language: those who know what they’re talking about are reluctant to beat a dead horse, so will abbreviate things. So, whenever you see statements like “a function $f$ has distributional derivative ___”, you should immediately think “the associated distribution $\phi_f$ has distributional derivative ___”. Once we get used to things, we also omit mention of the canonical injection $L^1_{\text{loc}}(U)\hookrightarrow \mathcal{D}(U)$ (which you denoted as $\phi$).

In your ‘proof’ you say $\langle(\phi_H)’,g\rangle=\int_{\Bbb{R}}H’g\,dx$, but this is not even the definition of $(\phi_H)’$. On the other hand, $H$ is differentiable on $\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ with $H’=0$ here, so as an element of $L^1_{loc}(\Bbb{R})$, we can say $H’=0$. Hence, $\phi_{H’}=0$ is the zero distribution. This shows that $(\phi_H)’=\delta\neq 0=\phi_{H’}$. This is characteristic of jump discontinuities in the derivative of a function: the associated distributional derivatives differ by a multiple of $\delta$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If we consider the compact set $[-1, 1]$, then $H$ is not differentiable over this set, so how can we globally say that $H' = 0$ or that $\phi_{H'} = 0$? If we are only considering sets that avoid the origin then the definition of $\phi_{H'}$ and $(\phi_H)'$ agree, so I am unclear on where the disagreement comes from.

Comment: Also to further go into the point about terminology, in his book on real analysis Folland says "By this procedure [using the definition of a distribution derivative iteratively]  we can define derivatives of arbitrary locally integrable functions even when they are not differentiable in the classic sense", but here as we mentioned he is not defining derivatives of these locally integrable functions, but rather on the distributions they induce, right?

Comment: @CBBAM when you talk about $\phi_{\text{something}}$, that something has to be a locally integrable function on $\Bbb{R}$. Now, $H$ is differentiable away from the origin with derivative $0$, so $H:\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb{R}$ has $H’=0$. Recall from classical Lebesgue integration theory that pointwise values aren’t really important. If you want to consider this function as an element of $L^1_{loc}(\Bbb{R})$, then it is equal to $0$ here. And ok if you want to be super precise, then consider the function $h:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, $h(x)=0$ for $x\neq 0$, and $h(0)$ be whatever you like.

Comment: then, this function $h$ is *equivalent* to the zero function, i.e $[h]=[0]$ (i.e $\int_{\Bbb{R}}|h|\,d\lambda=0$). So, this is what it means to consider the a.e defined function $H’$ as an element of a Lebesgue space. (cont)

Comment: I see, so the fact that $H' = 0$ a.e. is what allows you to conclude that $\phi_{H'} = 0$, which is of course not in agreement with the Dirac delta distribution.

Comment: (cont) now, there’s a notion of distributions being equal on a subdomain. Lets say we have two open sets $V\subset U\subset\Bbb{R}^n$, and say we have two distributions $S,T$ defined on $U$. We say *the distributions $S$ and $T$ agree on $V$* or *$S=T$ on $V$* to mean for every $g\in \mathcal{D}(V)$ (i.e $g\in C^{\infty}(U)$ with $\text{supp}(g)$ compact and contained in $V$), we require $\langle S,g\rangle=\langle T,g\rangle$. You can easily verify that with this definition, $\phi_{H’}$ and $(\phi_H)’$ (which are distributions on $U=\Bbb{R}$) agree on $V=\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: also regarding Folland’s text, yes. when talking about distributional derivatives of locally integrable functions he means distributional derivatives of the associated distribution. I’m sure he says somewhere in the beginning that ‘henceforth we shall make this identification’ or something along those lines when mentioning the canonical inclusion. My advice: continue reading folland’s text, and if you’re in doubt regarding precision, check if he has made a remark earlier (he usually does), and otherwise, rephrase things to your desired level of precision (that’s how you learn).

Comment: Got it, thank you very much for all your help, it really cleared things up!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question is ultimately that $L^1_{\text{loc}}(X)$ is a subset of the distributions on $X$ (assume $X$ is an open subset of a Euclidean space). This comes precisely from the "motivation": if $f$ is locally integrable and $g$ is continuous with compact support, its a hopefully simple proof to show that $fg$ is integrable.

Since test functions $g$ are defined to be smooth with compact support, this means that $D(f)(g)=\int_X fg dV$ defines $D(f)$ as a distribution for $f\in L^1_{\text{loc}}$ (you can check Schwarz estimates how you like).

Show that this is an injection (after identifying functions $f$ that are a.e. equal, of course) using bump functions for $g$ and I think that's what you're asking about? Good luck!